# Problem when measuring IntelliJ Spring Boot Test Coverage on multi module project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

In my case, I run my whole multi-module test on IntelliJ like this:

[image]

The test works as intended, but there is a problem with measuring the test coverage.

If I run "Run With Coverage", only the test coverage of a specific module is measured properly, and the rest is set at 0%. If I do the gradle test for each module, the coverage for that module is over 90%. It's only a problem when testing the entire module, how can I fix it?

Comment: which version of IDEA and which test framework do you use?

Comment: 2022.1.2 Ultimate Edition / JUnit5

Comment: there's at least one issue with gradle code coverage: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-296626. Does the coverage works ok if you run tests with IntelliJ runner (can be changed in 'Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Run tests using') ? You can also try to run on 2022.2 and see if anything changes